# Calling from rust backend to frontend

Tags: web3.js, rust

I have written a function in the rust backend that I wish to return a value (I64) from and I have written it as such:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use crate::state::*;

const SLOWSPEED_REWARD: i64 = 50;

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SlowSpeeding<'info> {
    #[account(mut, has_one = wallet_id)]
    pub ship_account: Account<'info, Ship>,
    pub wallet_id: Signer<'info>,
    //Constraint on system_program to make sure it is official SOLANA software
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

pub fn handler(ctx: Context<SlowSpeeding>, berth: i64, initial: i64, expected: i64) -> Result<i64> {
    //Accounts called here are deserialized
    let ship: &mut Account<Ship> = &mut ctx.accounts.ship_account;
    let _author: &Signer = &ctx.accounts.wallet_id;

    ship.berth_time = berth;
    ship.initial_berth_time = initial;
    ship.expected_berth_time = expected;

    let mut reward: i64 = 0;
    //Check that slow speeding did occur
    if initial < berth && (expected - berth).abs() >= 1000 {
        //Give a small margin for boat to reach, dont have to be exactly on time
        msg!("Thank you for slow speeding sufficiently!");
        reward = SLOWSPEED_REWARD;
        //Add transaction (fixed amt)

    } else if initial >= berth {
        msg!("Slow speeding did not occur!");

    } else {
        msg!("Partial slow speeding detected!");
        let expected_time_reduction:i64 = expected - initial;
        let actual_time_reduction: i64 = berth - initial;
        //Arrive closer to slow speed time -> get more reward
        let fraction: f64 = (1 as f64) - (actual_time_reduction / expected_time_reduction) as f64;
        reward = (fraction * (SLOWSPEED_REWARD as f64)) as i64;
    }

    Ok(reward)
}
```

However, on my front-end, when I tag it to a variable such as:

const x = await program.methods.slowSpeeding(....)....

this returns the signature of the transaction instead. Is there a way for my to return the reward variable from my backend? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
#[program]
```

Add this to your above code, where your mentioning the instructions.

So it would be like this.

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use crate::state::*;

const SLOWSPEED_REWARD: i64 = 50;

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SlowSpeeding<'info> {
    #[account(mut, has_one = wallet_id)]
    pub ship_account: Account<'info, Ship>,
    pub wallet_id: Signer<'info>,
    //Constraint on system_program to make sure it is official SOLANA software
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[program]
pub fn handler(ctx: Context<SlowSpeeding>, berth: i64, initial: i64, expected: i64) -> Result<i64> {
    //Accounts called here are deserialized
    let ship: &mut Account<Ship> = &mut ctx.accounts.ship_account;
    let _author: &Signer = &ctx.accounts.wallet_id;

    ship.berth_time = berth;
    ship.initial_berth_time = initial;
    ship.expected_berth_time = expected;

    let mut reward: i64 = 0;
    //Check that slow speeding did occur
    if initial < berth && (expected - berth).abs() >= 1000 {
        //Give a small margin for boat to reach, dont have to be exactly on time
        msg!("Thank you for slow speeding sufficiently!");
        reward = SLOWSPEED_REWARD;
        //Add transaction (fixed amt)

    } else if initial >= berth {
        msg!("Slow speeding did not occur!");

    } else {
        msg!("Partial slow speeding detected!");
        let expected_time_reduction:i64 = expected - initial;
        let actual_time_reduction: i64 = berth - initial;
        //Arrive closer to slow speed time -> get more reward
        let fraction: f64 = (1 as f64) - (actual_time_reduction / expected_time_reduction) as f64;
        reward = (fraction * (SLOWSPEED_REWARD as f64)) as i64;
    }

    Ok(reward)
}
```

The program field is an macro , which tells the anchor that this section is an instruction section . Via which the frontend will communicate with.

Comment: I actually already did this in my lib.rs file (this is not the lib.rs file but another file containing the instructions) where I called on the all the handler functions my code would require!